# Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates for a function that only depends on the angle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, harmonic-functions

I need to solve Laplace's equation:
$$\nabla^2\Phi = 0$$
with the boundary conditions:
$$\Phi(\theta=0)=0$$
$$\Phi(\theta=\pi)=a_1$$

In cylindrical coordinates ($r,\theta,z$), for $\Phi =\Phi(\theta)$ only. My first attempt at this yielded the following:
$$\require{cancel}\nabla^2\Phi = \cancel{\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} r\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial\theta^2}+\cancel{\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial z^2}}=0$$
$$\nabla^2\Phi = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial \theta^2} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial \theta^2} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta} = c$$
$$\Phi = c\theta + b$$
$$b = 0$$
$$a_1 = c\pi$$
$$c = \frac{a_1}{\pi}$$
$$\Phi = \frac{a_1}{\pi}\theta$$
Which looks nice, but I'm applying it to a physics problem (half-cylinder of uniform resistance $\rho$ with above boundary conditions), and I'm not coming out with the right units. I know that in evaluating a triple integral over the volume, I would need

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^h\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\Phi\ r\ dr\ dz\ d\theta$$
but can I even do what I'm trying to?